# Bootstrap 4 force parent container-fluid to include expanded dropdown

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Is there a way to get the parent div ".primaryNav", shown in the example with a red background, to include my horizontal dropdown menu in MD to XL views like it does on mobile view?

Currently, I need to add a margin to the .mainNav class to increase the container height so that the background color and drop shadow align with the bottom of the sub nav and the content below it are pushed down. The issue is that when there isn't a sub nav, then the container is too tall and there is a gap.

The goal is to get the .primaryNav div to grow and include the sub nav automatically, pushing down the main content area

```css
#topNav {
  letter-spacing: .06rem;
}

#topNav a.nav-link {
  padding: 0.05rem 0.5rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

#topNav a.nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#topNav a.nav-link.wpLink {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.primaryNav {
  background-color: red;
}

#mainNav .mainSearch .form-control {
  border-left: 0;
}

#mainNav .input-group-text {
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  #mainNav {
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1rem;
    font-weight: 800;
  }
  #mainNav .nav-link {
    min-height: 65px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #mainNav {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 800;
  }
  #mainNav .nav-link,
  #mainNav .nav-item {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  #mainNav,
  #mainNav .collapse,
  #mainNav .nav-link {
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
        -ms-flex-align: stretch;
            align-items: stretch;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #mainNav .nav-link span {
    -ms-flex-item-align: center;
        align-self: center;
  }
  #mainNav .nav-link:active,
  #mainNav .nav-link:focus,
  #mainNav .nav-link:hover {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }
  #mainNav .active .nav-link {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #0075C9;
  }
  #mainNav .dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
  #mainNav .dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-flow: row nowrap;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    background: white;
  }
  #mainNav .dropdown-menu.in,
  #mainNav .active .dropdown-menu,
  #mainNav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: flex !important;
  }
  #mainNav .dropdown-item {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    width: auto;
  }
  #mainNav .dropdown-item:hover,
  #mainNav .dropdown-item:focus,
  #mainNav .dropdown-item.active,
  #mainNav .dropdown-item:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #mainNav {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <title>Bootstrap Starter</title>


    <!-- Stylesheet -->

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Top Navigation -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-primary">
    <div class="container px-0">
        <nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark text-white px-0 justify-content-lg-end">
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex ">
                <li class="nav-item d-lg-none">
                    <a class="nav-link wpLink" href="#">Company</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Product Registration</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-block">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Main Navigation -->
<div class="container-fluid primaryNav m-sm-0 mb-sm-3 p-sm-0 border-bottom border-secondary shadow">
    <div class="container px-0 mainNav">
        <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light p-0">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-lg-block order-md-first" href="#">
                <img class="img-fluid py-2" src="assets/img/waterpik-shower-heads-logo.png">
            </a>
            <!-- Search Bar -->
            <form class="form-inline order-md-last m-0 my-2 my-md-0 flex-grow-1 flex-lg-grow-0">
                <div class="input-group mainSearch w-100">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Toggler -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mx-lg-5" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                      <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span>Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span>Shop Products</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item d-md-none" href="#">Shop All</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hand Held</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fixed Mount</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dual Head</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span>Shop Products 2</span>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink1">
                            <a class="dropdown-item d-md-none" href="#">Shop All</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item " href="#">Hand Held 2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fixed Mount 2</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dual Head 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- Main Content -->
<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <img src="assets/img/logo.png"/>
        <h1>Bootstrap 4 Starter Template</h1>
        <p class="lead">This example is a quick bootstrap starter template.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-test" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/" role="button" target="_blank">View Bootstrap 4.1 Docs <i class="fad fa-acorn"></i></a>
    </div>
</main>
 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clearer. I want the containing div .primaryNav to expand vertically to encompass the dropdown menu when it is exposed upon hover. Currently, it is showing outside of the div shown with a red background color.

Comment: My question only pertains to the desktop view of the code snippet. The hamburger menu works as expected. 

Is there a way to have the red main menu expand to surround the sub nav on hover without using height on the pseudo element?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<nav id="topNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-xs navbar-dark text-white px-0 justify-content-lg-end">
```

That should work too keep the burger menu, is that what you are trying to achieve? I could not find the div with a primaryNav class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your horizontal menu to be collapsed in MD to XL breakpoints as it is in mobile, you can use `.navbar-expand-*` class.

So, replace `navbar-expand-md` with `navbar-expand-xl` in `#mainNav` element.

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light p-0">
```